# Keeping version numbers in sync in angular library project package.json files

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-library, ng-packagr

When building an Angular Library application, is there an automated way to keep the root level package.json and the library application's package.json (e.g. under `projects/my-library`) file versions in sync when using `npm version` commands?

When I use the command, it's only incrementing the root level package.json, is there a special command, or any other way to propagate the version number down to the library package.json file?

I have seen some solutions such as running a script after `ng build` to read the root level package.json version number and write that into the library one but I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Has anyone else faced this when building libraries in Angular and if so what was your way to deal with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen people ask the same question to vsavkin (Nrwl/Nx dude) and his response was a fairly involved [git sub-module approach](https://blog.nrwl.io/dev-workflow-using-git-submodules-and-yarn-workspaces-14fd06c07964).

While this workflow is a little complex, it does allow shared libraries to be individually versioned whilst keeping them in the same parent git-repo.

---

A simpler alternative is, as you have already mentioned, to keep all libraries in a monorepo the same version as the root package.json - similar to how the Angular monorepo bumps its versions of all the Angular packages at the same time.

This can be done easily in node, or in bash/shell with a little bit more scripting.

[Here's a gist with node, bash & shell examples of how to extract the version from the root package.json](https://gist.github.com/DarrenN/8c6a5b969481725a4413).

---

To actually bump the versions of the packages here's a simple approach: install this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json) (a nice CLI for editing json files) and read the [In-Place editing section](http://trentm.com/json/#FEATURE-In-place-editing). You should now have all the tools you need!

---

Here's an example bash script using node:

```
cd libs/my-library && json -I -f package.json this.version=$(node -pe \"JSON.stringify(require('../../package.json').version)\")
```

Comment: In my case, I was forced to bump the version in the project `package.json` file, the child one not the parent work space one. I don't know why there are two versions properties in these two files. Now I'm trying to use your script with a bash find command to find the `package.json` file and read the version property from it.

Answer (score 3):

I use a combination of [sync-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-json) and "pre-post version" scripts to help with this.

```
npm i -D sync-json
```

Here's what my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "build:lib": "ng build --prod my-lib",
    "sync-version": "sync-json -v --property version --source package.json projects/my-lib/package.json",
    "preversion": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "version": "npm run sync-version && npm run build:lib && git add -A && git commit -m \"bump up\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  ...
}
```

Just for clarity:

1. "sync-version": copies the version from the main package.json and pastes it to the lib package.json
2. "prevention": cleans the workspace
3. "version": syncs versions, builds lib, commits changes
4. "postversion": git push everything

Answer (score 2):

For my Angular library, I was forced to bump the version in the project `package.json` file, the child one not the parent workspace one. So I needed to update the version property in the parent workspace `package.json` file.

```
├── package.json
└── projects
    └── lib-pwa
        └── package.json
```

For this I created in the `~/dev/commands/ng.sh` file the bash `ng-version-sync-parent` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
ng-version-sync-parent() {
  version=`find ./projects -name package.json -exec cat {} + | jq --raw-output '.version'`;
  echo 'Project package version: '$version;
  jq --arg version $version ".version = \"$version\"" package.json | sponge package.json
  version=`cat package.json | jq --raw-output '.version'`;
  echo 'Workspace package version: '$version;
}
```

I then used it in my workspace directory:

```
source ~/dev/commands/ng.sh
11:29 $ ng-version-sync-parent 
Project package version: 0.1.4
Workspace package version: 0.1.4
```

Answer (score 2):

npm 7 has support for [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces).

In npm 7 you can use workspaces with [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version)

You can add your workspaces to your package.json like this:

```json
{
   "name":"parent",
   "workspaces":[
      "projects/child-a",
      "projects/child-b"
   ]
}
```

When using workspaces npm version will not create a commit or tag (there could be version name conflicts).

If you might want to add the changed files, commit them and create a tag automatically for each workspace you can use a version script.

```json
"scripts": {
    "version": "git add . && git commit -m \"Version $npm_package_version\" && git tag v$npm_package_version",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
```

Keep in mind that tag names must be unique. You might want to prefix the name of the workspace to the tag.

And then run

```sh
npm version major --workspaces=true
```

Please note that Angular only supports the LTS version of node which may affect your ability to use workspaces in your build process.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following solution:

**Flow**:

`create-tarball` should be executed right after the library has been build. it means when the `ng build` was executed but automatically `precreate-tarball` is going to be executed before.

Then`create-tarball` will be executed.

Finally `postcreate-tarball` will be executed automatically too.

**Command explanation:**

`precreate-tarball`:  Update the package version in the workspace paths (In my case is the demo application and the library distribution folder). This is because its better update the version right after the ng build be success.

`create-tarball:` Build the pack for the distribution folder (tarball).

`postcreate-tarball:` It keeps the demo or parent package.json and the library package json synchronized

```
  {
     "build":"ng build",
     "postbuild": "npm run create-tarball"
     "precreate-tarball": "npm version prerelease --workspaces=true --no-git-tag-version --force",
     "create-tarball": "cd dist/my-library && npm pack",
     "postcreate-tarball": "sync-json -v --property version --source package.json projects/my-library/package.json",
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "./",
    "dist/my-library"
  ],
```

You can install [sync-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-json) from npm